# Android: RecyclerView item when set to clickable blocks onTouch events

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Looks like setting RecyclerView's item layout to clickable="true", consume *some* touch events completely, particulary `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` (ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP afterwards are working):

item.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/demo_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"> <-- this what breaks touch event ACTION_DOWN

....    
</LinearLayout>
```

Having very basic RecyclerView setup in onCreate():

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);    
... //Standard recyclerView init stuff

//Please note that this is NOT recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener()
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Log.d("", "TOUCH ---  " + motionEvent.getActionMasked());
                //Will never get here ACTION_DOWN when item set to android:clickable="true" 
                return false;
            }
      });
```

Is this intended behaviour or bug in RecyclerView cause it is still a preview?

PS. I want this to be clickable as per docs to react on pressed state and have ripple effect on click. When set to false ACTION_DOWN is working fine but pressed state is not triggered and selectableBackground does not have any effect.

Comment: Try setting `android:focusable="true"` , I haven't tested this, which is why I'm not providing it as an answer, but ACTION_DOWN to me seems like a focus related event.

Comment: @Iija, Did you get any solution? I am stuck on the same problem for quite a few days now.

Comment: @Manu, I ended up thinking this is intended behaviour. You should be able to achieve what you want by using recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener() instead....

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour NOT a bug.

When set item clickable true, ACTION_DOWN will be consumed, recycler view
will NEVER get ACTION_DOWN.

Why are you need ACTION_DOWN in onTouch() of recycler view? Does it necessary?
if you want to set lastY in ACTION_DOWN, why not this

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
        // initial
        if (lastY == -1)
            lastY = y;

        float dy = y - lastY;
        // use dy to do your work

        lastY = y;
        break;
    case:MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // reset
        lastY = -1;
        break;
```

Does it you want to? if you still want the ACTION_DOWN, try to get it in activity, such as:

```
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    lastY = ev.getRawY();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
```